# Spark connection to Metastore fails, on Kerberos, in cluster mode, works in client mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, kerberos, hive-metastore

We are running a standalone Spark 3.3.2 cluster from which we want to write/read from Iceberg tables.
To manage the metadata we want to use a standalone Metastore protected with Kerberos (provided by FeeIPA if it matters). For now we do not care about authorization, we just want to get identity confirmed by Kerberos.
Everything works for us when we run application in client mode, with a `kinit` done beforehand.
Everything also works in cluster mode if we first do a `kinit` as a spark user on each of the workers.

However we fail when we try to run it in cluster mode without `kinit` on workers. The error we get is:
`GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)`
In logs on debug level we see that application is not even trying to use Kerberos:
`23/06/06 12:08:56 DEBUG UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction [as: user (auth:SIMPLE)][action: org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1@5314d9b0]` 
When we enabled Kerberos debug we did not get any information (it either produce a lot of entries for a successful attempt or none at all for a failed.

We are starting our app like this:

```
spark-submit --class Main --conf "spark.cores.max=4" --deploy-mode cluster --master spark://sparkmaster01.domain:7090 --conf spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=s3a://hits/ --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type=hive --conf spark.sql.catalog.iceberg=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog --conf spark.sql.catalog.iceberg.warehouse=s3a://hits/ --packages org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.3_2.12:1.2.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.2,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.11.874 --files /etc/spark/core-site.xml KafkaToIceberg-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

But it also fails in the same way if we run just a spark-shell (with above parameters) and do `kdestroy` before we start.

We tried putting different things into jaas file (changing both parameters and section names) but nothing seams to change the behavior.

Our spark config taken from the session looks like (only properties that look relevant):

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -> -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/spark/security/client_jaas.conf
spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris -> thrift://metastore01.domain:9083
spark.sql.catalog.iceberg -> org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog
spark.ssl.enabled -> true
spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog -> org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog
spark.app.initial.file.urls -> spark://edge01.domain:4040/files/core-site.xml
spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.sasl.enabled -> true
spark.files -> file:///etc/spark/core-site.xml
spark.executor.id -> driver
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -> -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/spark/security/client_jaas.conf
spark.local.dir -> /data/tmp/spark-spill
spark.home -> /opt/apache/spark/spark-latest
spark.sql.catalogImplementation -> hive
spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.kerberos.principal -> metastore/metastore01.domain@GEMIUSPOC.LAN
spark.sql.extensions -> org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions
spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type -> hive
```

client_jaas.conf we pass to the driver and executors:

```
KafkaClient {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    refreshKrb5Config=true
    serviceName="kafka"
    debug=true
    doNotPrompt=false
    keyTab="/etc/spark/security/spark.keytab"
    principal="spark/edge01.domain@REALM.LAN";
};

Client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    storeKey=true
    refreshKrb5Config=true
    serviceName="metastore"
    debug=true
    doNotPrompt=false
    keyTab="/etc/spark/security/spark.keytab"
    principal="spark/edge01.domain@REALM.LAN";
};
```

Metastore configuration (only properties that looks relevant, in actual code it is a proper XML):

```
hive.metastore.sasl.enabled=true    
hive.metastore.kerberos.keytab.file=/etc/hive-metastore/security/hive.keytab
hive.metastore.kerberos.principal=metastore/_HOST@REALM.LAN
```

And `core-site.xml` on Metastore machine (in actual code it is a proper XML):

```
hadoop.security.authentication=kerberos
```

Could you please help us figure out what we are missing in our setup?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `--principal` and `--keytab` parameters to your spark submit

Comment: Adding these options does not change anything (apart from adding `spark.kerberos.principal` and `spark.kerberos.keytab` to configuration, but we still get the same Kerberos errors). Also help to `spark-submit` says that these options are applicable only to YARN and Kubernetes deployments, and not Standalone.